# Is it possible to save a word document by bypassing the Save or SaveAs methods c#

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, word-addins

I have a MS Word AddIn that launches a winform which allows the user to specify some additional metadata which is then saved as an xml file along with a copy of the document in a specified location.

This all works fine when run from a standalone Word document, however one of the areas this will be used is where a Word document is launched inside an application (EMIS WEB). It launches a copy of Word from the local machine which is fine as it allows the AddIn to be run.

When I try to save the document I get a `Command Failed.` error. The XML file saves no problem: `xml.Save(path + docName + ".xml");`.

The application prompts with it's own 'save' like dialog.

[image: 'Save' Like Dialog]

At first I thought it was the application removing focus from the document therefore `this.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs` failing because it wasn't the Active Document. So I tried getting the Document object when it was active and passing it through to the saveDoc method so that I could set it as the Active Document like so:

```
public void saveDoc(string doc, Word.Document wd)
{
    string path = @"\\servername\folder\subfolder\";
    object filename = path + doc + ".docx";
    try
    {
        wd.Activate();
        this.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref filename);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

However this made no difference, the application's dialog still pops up, and regardless of whether I click OK or Cancel to the dialog it does not process the SaveAs command.

I have come to the conclusion that the application is intercepting the Save/SaveAs command and doing its own thing instead.

So is it possible to save a word document by bypassing the Save or SaveAs methods? Is there a way round this?

Comment: FWIW it's possible to "hijack" some/many of Word's built-in commands, especially pre-Backstage, by having macros with the name of the built-in command: for example Sub FileSaveAs and Sub FileSave. If something like that has been done there's nothing you can do. Glad you found a way around it :-)

Comment: @Cindy That's good to know thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, fortunately there was not a strict requirement to save it as a `.doc` or `.docx` so I have opted for `.pdf`. I have got round the application intercepting the Save commands by using the [Document.ExportAsFixedFormat Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.exportasfixedformat.aspx) with `wdExportFormatPDF` to save it as a PDF.

So the final code looks like this, and it works a treat:

```
public void saveDoc(string doc)
    {
        string path = @"\\servername\folder\sub-folder\";
        string filename = path + doc + ".pdf";
        try
        {
            this.Application.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(filename, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```